# 301 redirects anything after it's directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I'm trying to set up some 301s and I'm realizing that the path get's redirected if there's anything after it's "sub directory" This is a cms site, so they aren't actual directories.

but for example

```
Redirect 301 /products http://example.com/products/all
```

is also redirecting /products/category and /products/category/category-name

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

That's how `Redirect` directives work. They effectively move the complete directory hierarchy i.e. sub-directories or files specified after the original path are appended to the target URL.

If that's an undesired side-effect for you, switch to a `RedirectRule` as

```
RedirectRule ^products/?$ /products/all [R=301,L]
```

I'm assuming you're redirecting within the same site. If not, you would specify the full target URL as before.

```
RedirectRule ^products/?$ http://example.com/products/all [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive can be seen as "virtually" linking two URL-path nodes. So:

```
Redirect /A /B
```

is like shortcuting the folder A to the folder B. So that would include everything *inside* folder A as well.

If you want only a specific URL to be redirected, use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /products/?$ http://example.com/products/all
```